# when nhibernate generates a schema, what about other indexes besides PK and FK

Tags: nhibernate

If I let nhibernate generate the schema, what about other indexes I may put on the tables for performance reasons?

e.g. say I need to order by a datetime field allot, I may put a index on that column.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a single-column unique index by specifying `unique="true"` in a class property's mapping.

You can create a multi-column unique index by giving each participating property the same `unique-key="foo"` value.

You can create a multi-column, non-unique index the same way, except the attribute to use is `index="bar"` instead of `unique-key="foo"`.

Finally, for more complex cases, you can create the index inside a `<database-object>` element in the mapping file.